# Yii behaviors won't save data

Tags: php, yii, many-to-many, behavior

I'm trying to save relations in third table 'Relations'. Here's code:

Controller save action:

```
$relations = $_POST['VideoCaptions']['countries'];
                $model->attachBehavior('ManyToManyRelationBehavior', array(
                    'class' => 'ManyToManyRelationBehavior',
                    'modelNameRelation' => 'Relations',
                    'firstField' =>  'video_captions',
                    'secondField' => 'video_countries',
                    'relationList' => $relations,
                ));
```

ManyToManyRelationBehavior class afterSave action:

```
    if (is_array($this->relationList)){
                $model_ = $this->modelNameRelation;
                $model_::model()->deleteAll("first_field = :firstField AND first_field_value = :firstFieldValue AND second_field = :secondField", array(
                    ":firstField" => $this->firstField,
                    ":firstFieldValue" => $this->owner->id,
                    ":secondField" => $this->secondField
                ));
                foreach ($this->relationList as $value){
                    $model_ = new $this->modelNameRelation;
                    $model_->first_field = $this->firstField;
                    $model_->first_field_value = $this->owner->id;
                    $model_->second_field = $this->secondField;
                    $model_->second_field_value = intval($value);
                    if (!$model_->save()) return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
```

var_dump($model_) returns that model exists, but $model->save() doesn't save any data in table 'Relations'. I can't understand why. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

```
    foreach ($this->relationList as $value){
        $model = new $this->modelNameRelation;
        $model->first_field = $this->firstField;
        $model->first_field_value = $this->owner->id;
        $model->second_field = $this->secondField;
        $model->second_field_value = intval($value);
        Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->insert($model->tableName(), $model->attributes);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What are the validations you set up for this "modelNameRelation"? You should try the insert() method instead of save() and check whether it will work or not? Save first validates then call insert() or update() method.

Comment: array('first_field, first_field_value, second_field, second_field_value', 'required')

Comment: Relations::model()->insert($model->attributes) returns error: "The active record cannot be inserted to database because it is not new."

Comment: $model_->insert() try this only instead of $model_->save()

Comment: same "The active record cannot be inserted to database because it is not new."

Comment: Let's try $model_->update() ... it is cleared that your delete query isn't deleting the previous records.

Comment: Solved by this: Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->insert($sup->tableName(), $sup->attributes);